# How to Write query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables as:

```
mysql> select * from survey;
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
| survey_id | client_id | stage_id | by_ref | no_branch |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
|         2 |        65 |       72 | P      | 15        |
|         3 |        67 |       72 | D      | 2         |
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from allcode where code_type="MARKETING_STAGES";
+------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
| code_type        | code_id | srno | code_name          |
+------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
| MARKETING_STAGES |      72 |    1 | Enquiry            |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      73 |    3 | Meeting            |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      74 |    4 | Presentation       |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      75 |    5 | Review / Follow up |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      76 |    6 | Negotiation        |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      77 |    7 | Order              |
| MARKETING_STAGES |      78 |    8 | Agreement          |
| MARKETING_STAGES |     162 |    9 | Complete           |
| MARKETING_STAGES |     163 |    2 | Tender             |
+------------------+---------+------+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I want to update `stage_id` of **survey** table to next value which will be fetch from **allcode** `code_id`.
Right now I have `client_id` i.e. 65 from `survey` table, and want to update `stage_id` to **163** ( i.e. **Next code_id from allcode table on sorting based on `srno`** )

What I have tried till is

```
update survey as s 
set s.stage_id=
(select code_id from allcode 
where code_id > (select stage_id from (select * from survey where client_id=65 )as su) 
and code_type="MARKETING_STAGES"
limit 1) 
where client_id=65;
```

This query update `stage_id` of **allcode** to **73** and I want it to be updated to **163** (Depending on `srno`)

Comment: Allcode table does not have code_type field. Your query is extremely convoluted, full of unnecessary subqueries.

Comment: to make it simple I have removed it

Comment: Difficult to say - but would it be easier to change it so that stage_id was the srno, so rather than this awkward translation, you simply have the (I assume) step number in this table.

Comment: @Shadow updated with code_type field in allcode table

Comment: @NigelRen `srno` are step numbers

Comment: Do you want to set the stage_id to select max(code_id) from allcode? Can't the below subquery select stage_id from (select * from survey where client_id=65 )as su
be changed to
(select stage_id from survey where client_id=65 )as su
unless I am missing something? Can you paste the schema for both the tables?

Comment: not `max(code_id)` but **NEXT** corresponds to `srno`

Comment: is srno linked to survey_id?

Comment: Can you store `srno` in survey instead of `stage_id` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use joins in the update to get the next `code_id` based on `srno`:

```
update survey s
inner join allcode a1 on s.stage_id=a1.code_id
inner join allcode a2 on a1.srno=a2.srno-1
set s.stage_id=a2.code_id
where a1.code_type='MARKETING_STAGES' and a2.code_type='MARKETING_STAGES' and s.client_id=65
```

I assumed that `srno` field increments by 1 without any gaps. The purpose of the 1st join is to get the current stage_id's srno. Then the 2nd join gets the stage_id for the next srno.

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: its working, will test and let you know if any problem

Comment: Definitely better than other answers as it not only fixes the problem, but also does it more efficiently.

Comment: why `a1.code_type='MARKETING_STAGES' and a2.code_type='MARKETING_STAGES'`

Comment: Since you have a code type field, I assume you store process steps for multiple processes in the allcode table. These filter criteria make sure that the steps only from the markeing process are considered.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing an `order by` before `limit` in subquery.

So without touching your rest of the query, I just tried adding an `order by` and it seems to update first `stage id` from `72` to `163` as you want.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HEALM22609)**

```
update survey as s 
set s.stage_id=
(select code_id from allcode 
where code_id > (select stage_id from (select * from survey where client_id=65 )as su) 
and code_type="MARKETING_STAGES"
ORDER BY SRNO
limit 1) 
where client_id=65;
```

Comment: Why the down-vote as, per demo it seems to do what OP wants?

Comment: It is convoluted and full of unnecessary subqueries.

Comment: Agreed. But I just wanted to fix the problem which OP mentioned, saying it is updating it to `73` instead of `163` and I saw that he is missing `order by`. So I just pointed that out. Anyways your answer is better as it not only fixed the problem, but also does it more efficiently.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to comment earlier so my memory may be incomplete, but FYI I think you merely had an issue with syntax.  `set s.stage_id=` should have just been `set stage_id=`.  Using your query, I got: `ERROR:  column "s" of relation "survey" does not exist`.  Sometimes it's the silly little things.